# wxPython events not handled?

Tags: event-handling, wxpython

I wrote a simulator for a microcontroller where I pass the results of the functions with events to the GUI. The problem is that the functions bound to the events never got called.
I have the GUI and the simulator in two different threads.

```
'''Event class'''
NewRAMEvent = wx.NewEventType()
EVT_NEW_RAM = wx.PyEventBinder(NewRAMEvent, 1)

class RAM_Event(wx.PyCommandEvent):
    def __init__(self, location = None, val = None):
        wx.PyCommandEvent.__init__(self)
        self._location = location
        self._val = val

    def SetVals(self, val, loc):
        self._location = loc
        self._val = val

    def GetVal(self):
        return self._val

    def GetLocation(self):
        return self._location


    '''Creating event'''
    evt1 = RAM_Event(0x03, uC.programCounter)
    wx.CallAfter(recipient.ProcessEvent, evt1)
    print("RAM event sent")

    '''adding recipient to list and creating thread for simulator'''
    simuThread = SimulatorThread()
    simuThread.add_event_recipient(Myfrm)


    '''GUI class'''
    self.Bind(EVT_NEW_RAM, self.updateRAM)

    def updateRAM(self, event):
        print("received Event")
        location = event.GetLocation()
        value = event.GetVal()
        print("value:", value)
        RAM.writeToTable(self, location, value)
        return
```

When I look at the console I see the message that it has been sent but not that it has been received.

Answer (score 1):

Your `RAM_Event` never sets its event type to `NewRAMEvent`. You may want to take a look at the `wx.lib.newevent` module, as it can take care of most of these details for you. You can create the new event type and event class with just a single line, like:

`NewRAMEvent, EVT_NEW_RAM = wx.lib.newevent.NewCommandEvent()`

The generated class will accept arbitrary keyword parameters which it will then assign as attributes of the class instance.

Also, `wx.PostEvent(recipient, evt1)` would be a little better way to send the event than using the `wx.CallAfter`. It's basically equivalent, but `wx.PostEvent` is deigned for events and so it saves a few steps internally.